# Auth0: authenticated() incorrectly returning false after redirect following successful login

Tags: angular, auth0

I'm using Auth0 with Angular 2. Everything seems to be working, however, I would like to automatically open the login popup if the user isn't logged in when the page loads, so I added the following code inside the constructor of my auth.service.ts file:

```
// If user isn't logged in, invoke login popup (my custom method)
if (!this.authenticated()){
    this.login();
}
// Add callback for lock `authenticated` event (default method from Auth0)
this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult:any) => {
    ...
});
```

This works great on a page refresh, both when the user isn't logged in and  when they are logged in, however, there is one scenario where it doesn't work properly. Right after I log in, it automatically redirects me back to my specified redirectUrl, as it should, but the problem is after that redirect following a successful login, `this.authenticated()` returns false as if I'm not logged in, so after every successful login, the login popup displays.

It takes a moment after the redirect for the `authenticated()` method to accurately reflect my login status. How can I implement this code to get it to work in all scenarios, including after a successful login and subsequent redirect?

Comment: any finding on this, I am getting the same issue?

Comment: @vimalDev Sorry, I can't remember. I'm using Firebase Authentication instead now so I can't even check.